# Mutual or individual Kubernetes clusters?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

We have different saas applications to deploy for our clients with 2 different configurations: some applications are exclusive to some clients (one or multiple apps for a single client) while others are shared between clients (same app for all clients but with different accounts). What's the best strategy (in terms of HA, security, etc.) to deploy them: using a big single mutual Kubernetes cluster for all of our clients or individual kubernetes cluster for each different client?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is somewhat opinion based, but given you have [resource limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/), [network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), [namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) and [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) you can use a single cluster for multiple clients.

You just have to make sure your cluster is resilient to failures if you have a single cluster for everything. For example, in [AKS you can use availability zones](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/availability-zones-az-support-for-aks/)